# Filtering out numbers that have sequential- consecutive or non-consecutive digits

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, perl

I have a file filled with numbers, number per line. Each number consists of two or three digits.

I would like to filter out this file by any number has two or more sequential digits. These sequential digits can be consecutive (e.g. 127, 215, 781), or non-consecutive (e.g. 506). The order of the sequential digits is not important. It can be small to large (e.g. 127) or large to small (e.g. 215).

For example:

```
127
215
781
874
370
01
10
142
506
94
```

The expected output:

```
370
94
```

Because:

```
127 # Has two sequential and consecutive digits (1 and 2)
215 # Has two sequential and consecutive digits (1 and 2)
781 # Has two sequential and consecutive digits (7 and 8)
874 # Has two sequential and consecutive digits (7 and 8)
370 # Keep
01  # Has two sequential and consecutive digits (0 and 1)
10  # Has two sequential and consecutive digits (0 and 1)
142 # Has two sequential and non-consecutive digits (1 and 2)
506 # Has two sequential and non-consecutive digits (5 and 6)
94  # Keep
```

Comment: You should show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Otherwise you seem to be attempting to get someone to do your homework for you without making any effort yourself.

Answer (score 8):

With `awk` and setting FS to empty string (the effect of using empty FS is undefined behavior per POSIX and depending on what version `awk` you are using it's can be result differently). Below is tested in GNU `awk`:

```
awk -F '' '{
             is_sequential=0;
             for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
                 is_sequential+=($0 ~ $i-1 || $0 ~ $i+1)
}!is_sequential' infile
```

we are checking on each number `$i` for a number that it's equal with number-1 `$i-1` or number+1 `$i+1` against the whole line, meaning that if there was a number `number-1` or `number+1` or both seen in a line, so we found there are at least two numbers are next to each other (the first, the number `$i`  itself and next one either `$i-1` or `$i+1` or both (sequential) and so the value of *is_sequential* variable will be incremented otherwise it will remain 0.

With `!is_sequential`, we print that line where the value is unchanged (the value is still `0`, no at least two numbers seen that were sequential); see also [What is the meaning of '1' at the end of an awk script](/q/63891/72456)

---

Or with any awk:

```
awk '{
       is_sequential=0;
       for (i=1; i<=length(); i++) {
           num=substr($0, i, 1)
           is_sequential+=($0 ~ num-1 || $0 ~ num+1)
       }
}!is_sequential' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try either

```
awk '
  {split ("", N)                    # delete array N
    L = 1                           # initialise boolean L to TRUE
    for (i=1; i<=length($1); i++){  # for each digit
      P = substr($1, i, 1)                   
      if (N[P-1] || N[P+1]){        # if contiguous digit exists,
        L = 0          
        break                       # set L to FALSE; and quit the for loop
      }
      N[P] = 1
    } 
  }
  L
' file
```

Output:

```
370
94
```

or

```
awk '
  {split ("", N)
    L = 1
    for (i=1; i<=length; i++)
      N[substr($0,i,1)] = 1      # set all N elements for the digits in string

    for (i=0; i<9; i++)
      if (N[i] + N[i+1] == 2) {  # check for two adjacent elements to be TRUE
        L = 0          
        break
      }
  }
L
' file
```

Output:

```
370
94
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Here, as the list of combinations is relatively small, you might as well consider them all in a ERE alternation:

```bsh
grep -vE '0.*1|1.*[02]|2.*[13]|3.*[24]|4.*[35]|5.*[46]|6.*[57]|7.*[68]|8.*[79]|9.*8'
```

The same with `perl` but using perl code in `(??{...})` inside the regexp to match the next or previous digit:

```bsh
perl -ne 'print unless /([0-8]).*(??{$1+1})/ || /([1-9]).*(??{$1-1})/'
```

With sed, you could append the list of consecutive pairs to the pattern space, and use back references to find the matches:

```bsh
sed -ne '1{x;s/$/0123456789876543210/;x;}' -e 'G;/\(.\).*\(.\).*\n.*\1\2/!P'
```