# Print only the lines that have specific properties

Tags: command-line

LlI have a text file i want to separate the output in one command as below:

1. Print all lines that have all consecutive duplicates characters.
2. Print all lines with all consecutively repeated characters except the last one or the last two characters in the same line.
3. Print all lines with all consecutively repeated characters except the first one or the first two characters in the same line.

Example: 
    11122323
    1112266 
    44778 
    223334456 
    6778811
     845511
     3357788

The output should be

```
1112266   >>>>> All repeated characters. 
44778     >>>>> All repeated except the last character.
223334456   >>> All repeated except the last two characters
6778811    >>>> All repeated except the first character.
845511     >>>> All repeated except the first two characters.
```

Non-repeating characters are allowed, but only if 1st or 2nd from start or end of a line. First line excluded becuse it has #3 is not consecutively repeated.

Comment: This is same question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472285/edited-print-only-the-lines-that-have-specified-properties

Comment: I tried many many times to solve it but no way

Comment: perl -lne '($copy = $_) =~ s/(.)\1//g; print if $copy' INFILE

Comment: I have to ask for your help and i will study the answer

Comment: Can i know what is the sticking point?

Comment: The question is clear and with all needed details

Comment: @Zahi `3357788` is excluded because `5` is not repeated.  Non-repeating character are allowed, but only if 1st or 2nd from  start or end.

Comment: @Zahi not repeated characters are allowed only if they are the first one or the first two characters in aline and also alowed if they are the last one or the last two characters in a line

Comment: @Kusalananda where is your post i kept studying it but now its removed

Comment: @Ahmed I deleted it because it was wrong and I'm too tired to come up with a solution that works at the moment. I may revisit it tomorrow, possibly.

Answer (score 1):

Slight adaption to the [recent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472010/303610) to your similar problem:

```
awk '
        {split ("", N)                                                  # delete N array
         P = 1                                                          # reset boolean L used for print decision
         L = length
         for (i=1; i<=L; i++) N[substr($0, i, 1)]+=((i<3)||(i>L-2))?2:1 # calculate  char count; doubly weigh leading/trailing
         for (n in N)   if (N[n] < 2)   {P = 0                          # for non-duplicate chars: set print decision
                                         break                          # and quit the for loop
                                        }

        }
P                                                                       # print if non-duplicate chars exist only at margins
' file
1112266
44778
223334456
6778811
845511
```

Comment: Dear RudiC your answer need some modification because if i have 1111323 in input it will be included in the output but it has to be excluded because it has three non repeated characters from end. For Example (1111323 excluded) but (1111332 included) (11113324 included) in the output.

Comment: Dear Ahmed, how about applying what you learned so far and analysing / modifying the proposal yourself? The proposal behaves exactly as specified, and it yields the desired output from your question. `1111323` has `3` duplicated, and `2` in the second last position, so the spec says it has to be printed.

Comment: could you please just show me how to tell awk  that what i mean with duplicates is 1113355 but not 1331515 the repeated characters are one beside one with no seperation. Thanks

Comment: could you please just show me how to tell awk  that what i mean with duplicates is 1113355 but not 1331515 the repeated characters are one beside one with no seperation. Thanks

Comment: Two days ago i'm trying to print the lines that all with only consecutive duplicates characters but coud'nt any help?

Comment: @@RudiC I solved my question to fined the lines with all consecutively repeated characters with sed -Ee '/^((.)\2+)+$/!d'  input.txt, but how to insert this command into awk above command to deal with consecutively repeated characters instead of only repeated characters keeping the above question parameters?